# Always on push notification on ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: push-notification, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I'm making Blazor WebAssembly with push notification like Android notification.

I already done it and it works. But the problem is, when I am not using the apps for half and hour or more, the notification didn't arrive. But when I use it and I leave the app for 5 minutes or so, the notification arrived.

Can you help me how to make my app always on, even when in background?

Comment: Check your service worker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app/_static/image7.png?view=aspnetcore-5.0 and post your source code.

Comment: i dont have any waiting service worker. its the latest